# HeaderHandler by AuthorizationHandler : No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to handle Headers obbligatoriety for an asp.net core web api proj using ***AuthorizationHandler***

I wrote my Handler and Requirement classes:

**Handler class**:

```
public class HttpHeaderHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HttpHeaderRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;
        private readonly ILogger<HttpHeaderHandler> _logger;

        public HttpHeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<HttpHeaderHandler> logger)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            HttpHeaderRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[requirement.Header]))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
                _logger.LogWarning($"Policy validation for header {requirement.Header} failed");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Requirement class**

```
public class HttpHeaderRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public HttpHeaderRequirement(string header)
        {
            Header = header;
        }

        public string Header { get; }
    }
```

So I added it into the ConfigurationServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HttpHeaderRequirement",
                                  policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SRN.Microservice.Commons.Authorization.HttpHeaderRequirement("Auth_Token")));
            });
        }
```

so I've created my Controller class using the Authorization implemented:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Policy = "HttpHeaderRequirement")]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
       [....]
    }
```

When I try to call my API the server returns the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: Not sure what is your authentication scheme,just add the code like:`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mis-using the authorization system in this case if you are not interested in an authenticated user.

Authorization is designed to say "if you require authorisation, you will be challenged to provide authentication details" after which it can run the handlers. In your case, you have not configured any authentication (because you are not actually checking the logged in user?).

In your case, what do you want to happen? If you simply want to return an error page, you could write your own attribute that is nothing to do with built-in authorization and runs on the action to return the error page based on your existing logic.

If you instead intend that the missing header *does* require authentication, then you will need to add and configure authentication.

**Edit**

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-filters for details of action filters

Comment: I'm interested in a more elaborate answer. What if the users of my API do not have to log in (public API) but I do need to return 403 sometimes, for example if the person paying me to have this API didn't pay me. I'm doing the same as OP, and getting the same error.